# Null body response to ALB from lambd function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to send some logs from the AWS Lambda function to the ALB.

I am using `StringIO` as handler for the logger.

Below is the snippet of the code

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

response_logger = logging.getLogger("ResponseLogger")
response_str = StringIO()
response_handler = logging.StreamHandler(response_str)
response_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
response_logger.addHandler(response_handler)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusDescription": "200 OK",
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": 'text/html'
        }
            }
    response['body'] = json.dumps(response_str.getvalue())
    return response
```

Expectation:
The body should return logs in html format.

Output:
body is null

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your function. It should be:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusDescription": "200 OK",
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        "headers": {
        "Content-Type": 'text/html'
        }
            }
    response['body'] = json.dumps(response_str.getvalue())

    return response
```

Comment: I did add the return response forgot to include that in the code. The main issue is that the ```response_str.getvalue()``` is returning null but on local it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to forget to return your function

just add `return response` at the bottom of your function

Comment: I did include the return response at the end but still I am getting the value as null for body